# Could not connect to remote facade url

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, tdd, eclipse-plugin, mxunit

I am trying to use [mxunit](http://mxunit.org/) eclipse plug-in for testing my test cases.
I am using eclipse 3.6.0 with cfml plug-in ([cfeclipse](http://www.cfeclipse.org) ver 1.4.2.*) For ColdFusion project.

On the fifth step of [plug-in configuration](http://wiki.mxunit.org/display/default/Configure+and+Test+the+Plugin?showComments=true), I get the following error:

Could not connect to facade URL.

Try running this in a browser:

http://localhost/mxunit/framework/RemoteFacade.cfc?wsdl&method=ping

In console, I get (504)Proxy Timeout error

However Above url works perfectly (returns true for ping method) in my browser after giving ColdFusion admin password
I also provided authentication in project properties for mxunit. (right click on project -> properties -> mxunit)

Plug-in does not load it's test methods automatically. Please help.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding the proxy information into eclipse itself: Preferences > General > Network Connections : Proxy Entries (you might be able to get this information from your browser's network settings)

The username/password in the MXUnit preferences is for basic auth, which is not the same thing as proxy configuration, I don't think.  More a website deal than a network deal, per se.